# Bash - No such file, yet the file exists

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, debian

I recently installed a `Debian Jessie amd64` headless server (using one of the netinstalls). The server is up and running and the system is working as expected.
But then I compiled a `.cgi` (written in C++). The compilation (using `g++ 4.9.2`) went well but as soon as I try to execute the file from `bash` it says `No such file or directory`.
As I read through other posts regarding this error I tried utilizing the `file`, `ldd` and even the `cat` command, but all of them say they can't find that file.
`ls -l` shows the file with `755` permission as expected.
But the bash-completion does nothing, it doesn't autocomplete the path.

But now it gets interesting:
Using `midnight commander` I can successfully read, edit and execute the binary and `apache` lists the complete directory index including the `.cgi` and would even let me download it.

What is going on?
Since I could execute it from `mc` I don't suppose it's about the executable itself.
Could the bash be corrupted?
Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: Are you using btrfs, by anyc hance?

Comment: Sadly not, it's ext4.

Comment: What is the *exact* filename of the executable?

Comment: It's just `index.cgi`. No spaces or other hidden characters...

Comment: Do you have a file called `.hidden` somewhere?

Comment: Nope, there is no such file in the whole filesystem.

Comment: Can you run that command in the directory of the file: `find . -name "*index.cgi*" -exec sh -c 'echo -n "$1" | xxd' _ {} \;` and post the output?

Comment: It prints nothing, `find` fails to find the file.

Comment: So the file has a special filename; it's not `index.cgi`. Please use `find . -exec sh -c 'echo -n "$1" | xxd' _ {} \;` in that directory and post the relevant part.

Comment: Goddamit! Instead of a normal `i` it got a `î` (with accent or whatever). Thanks man for pointing me in the right direction! If you post this as an answer I'll give you an accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for that file in the directory and hexdump all filenames like this:

```
find . -exec sh -c 'echo -n "$1" | xxd' _ {} \;
```

It prints (for example):

```
0000000: 2e2f 696e 6465 782e 6367 69              ./index.cgi
0000000: 2e2f 696e 6465 782e 6367 690a            ./index.cgi.
```

The second line `index.cgi` has a newline at the end (`0a`). You can look how the name of the file is and compare it with the first line in my example output. If everything is correct, the filename should look exactly like in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `updatedb` command.
This will going to update your directory database. 
Please see reference for more info  [updatedb Docs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/updatedb)